# Mac OSX bring the console window front most with shell command

Tags: macos, console

Here I want to ask you to help to bring the console window top most with a shell command. Is it possible?

there was a script execution in my work environment, and will take about several minutes to complete, I will move to other work while running, it is better there are some tips to notify me when script completes run.

So I think bring the window top most is the most direct way.

Please tell me how to achieve this, I'm working on windows, new to MacOS.
Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to bring the console window to the front, but if you're working in the terminal, you could do something like:

```
$ path/to/script ; tput bel
```

or

```
$ path/to/script ; say "script 1 is done"
```

Where `path/to/script` is whatever your usual method of loading the script is.

I recommend the first method, as it flashes the screen, makes a beeping noise, and causes the terminal icon to bounce up and down on my dock in OS X 10.10. The second might be better if you need to figure out which script is done from among a bunch of scripts. If you have coworkers who you don't want to disturb, you can change the preferences in terminal so that an alert only flashes the screen and doesn't also make a noise.

If you have access to the source code of the script, you can also add `tput bel` or `say "command"` to the last line of the script and you'll get the same behvaior.

Comment: Thanks mchenja, I used the 2nd method, say 'something'; for the 1st one is too 'quick' to notice in same cases;

Comment: sure, no problem. I'd bet that there is an applescript command to bring the console window to the front, though - maybe look through the applescript documentation if you get sick of my workaround?